# Buzz using jquery

Tags: jquery

How do I implement BUZZ (Yahoo chat buzzing) or shaking window functionality using jQuery?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know Yahoo chat buzzing but googling for `jquery shake` gives me:

http://codingstuffsbykiran.blogspot.com/2014/06/jquery-shake-effect-part-2.html

http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Effects/Shake

http://designshack.co.uk/articles/creating-a-shaking-login-form